# How to set Background image fit to the element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have an image for my button's background image. but, the image is not fit to the element inside `<li>` tag. But if I placed my button inside ouside `<li>`, it will resulting the expected result.

Here's example for image inside `<li>`

[image: Result]

and this is the image outside `<li>`

[image]

here's my `<html>` code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right p-2 text-center w-20em" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
            <li>
                <img src="~/images/user.png" class="rounded-circle img-fluid p-3 w-50">
                <p>
                    Someone's Name
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <!-- Here's the link code -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a class="btn-gold form-control" asp-page="/Password/Edit">Change</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a class="btn-gold form-control" asp-page="/Auth/Logout">Logout</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

and this is my custom class for `btn-gold`

```
.btn-gold {
  background: url(/images/button.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  color: white;

  &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

can someone help me to fit the image inside `<li>` tag? Thanks

Comment: Anyway you can get a jsFiddle or a snippet to demonstrate the actual code to achieve your current button layout?

Comment: Honestly, I never use snippet nor jsFiddle before. May I ask how to include bootstrap 4 to the snippet? or which part of code that I need to write down there? because I already write my code, and the my current layout is not achieved in the snippet @GrandIQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to achive is a rounded corner style, the best way to achieve that is by styling the button with css using the ***border-radius*** and the bootstrap ***btn class*** properties.

see [this link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) for more info. Do not forget to add the !important value on css if you want to make changes over bootstrap clases.

Note that it's a **better practice** to make the use of styles and classes instead of images, since images will make your application less responsive and more rigid to handle. see [this](https://robertnyman.com/2010/04/21/using-css-instead-of-images-when-coding-your-web-design/) for more info.

```css
.round{
border-radius: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap importation -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Basic</button> This has default bootstrap round corners<br>

<br>if somehow you are using links try the link tag:<br>

<br><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" aria-disabled="true">this is a link</a> here we made use of the "role" option and the bootstrap classes<br>

<h2> Changing round corners</h2><br>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary round">Basic</button> 30px round corner. notice how we also made the use of "!important" property on css in order to override bootstrap's default css properties<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `form-control` class for button type and add the padding to visible the button background image. Hope this solution will be helpful.

```css
.btn-gold {
  background: url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/Z/c/6/W/I/small-button-md.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  color: white !important;
  padding: 8px 20px 12px 20px;
  cursor:pointer;    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="p-2 text-center w-20em" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
    <li>
        <img src="~/images/user.png" class="rounded-circle img-fluid p-3 w-50">
        <p>
            Someone's Name
        </p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <!-- Here's the link code -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <a class="btn-gold" asp-page="/Password/Edit">Change</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <a class="btn-gold" asp-page="/Auth/Logout">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```